# Why are the twitter-bootstrap styles for button set to overflow:visible?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, css-frameworks

Why are the twitter-bootstrap styles for button set to overflow:visible?

Like this:

```
button{
  overflow:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It belongs to [Normalize.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.4/less/normalize.less#L262-L268) not twitter bootstrap. It is used to reset the value of `overflow` to `visible` as it is set to `hidden` in IE 8/9/10/11 by default.

```
//
// Address `overflow` set to `hidden` in IE 8/9/10/11.
//

button {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,but it is visible in IE 8/9/10/11
[http://codepen.io/Dudy/pen/KpPyBZ](http://codepen.io/Dudy/pen/KpPyBZ)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

> **Visible**:
>
> visible Default value. Content is not clipped, it may be rendered
> outside the content box.

If overflow is `auto` or `scroll` it will add scroll-bar to button.
That's why Twitter bootstrap used `overflow:visible;` so that button will be rendered outside the [content box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model).